# Add element to list before specific element

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of items, lets say 100 items. I need to add another element before the existing element that matches my condition. What is the fastest way and the most performance optimized to do this? 
ie.:

```
foreach (var i in myList)
{
    if (myList[i].value == "myValue")
    {
        myList[i-1] add ("someOtherValue")
    }
}
```

Maybe i should use other container?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First you could find the index of your item using [`FindIndex` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx):

```
var index = myList.FindIndex(x => x.value == "myvalue");
```

Then [`Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) at the right point:

```
myList.Insert(index,newItem);
```

Note that inserting at a given index pushes everything else forward (think about finding your item at index 0).

Comment: But what if the condition is an element of a collection? In other words, "myvalue" is an element of List<conditions> ? Will that couse errors if I use foreach loop to compare all values in 'myList' with all elements form 'conditions' ?

Answer (score 5):

Consider using a `LinkedList<T>`. It has the advantage that inserting or removing items does not require shifting any items. The disadvantage is that items cannot be accessed randomly. You have to traverse the list starting at the first or last item in order to access the items.

Answer (score 3):

```
myList.Insert(myList.IndexOf("myValue") - 1, "someOtherValue");
```

You should probably check to make sure myvalue exists first, and it is not in index 0.

Comment: This assumes its `List<string>` and the OP's items have a `value` property which implies its a custom type.

Comment: @Jamiec Title says list, tag says list. OP never claimed that code was even valid.

Answer (score 3):

```
int index = myList.IndexOf("myValue");
if (index >= 0)
  myList.Insert(index, "myNewValue");
```

By the way, you should not modify your own collection or list while iterating with for-each (as in your code above).

Comment: +1 for the comment. I think it'll throw a runtime exception if you do that.

Comment: what if there's more than one myValue ?

Comment: Depends on the question - if the element should be inserted before the first occurrence of that item or everywhere. There are different IndexOf methods to find out all occurances. when inserting one need to advance the index by 1 anytime.

Answer (score 1):

I presume the list is an array - in which case have you tried doing this with Linq?

```
string[] mylist = new string[100];
// init the list
List<string> list = keys.ToList();
list.Insert(1,"somethingelse");
mylist = list.ToArray(); // convert back to array if required
```

if it is a `List` to begin with, you can skip the conversions and use `Insert` directly.